# Snubber circuit with MOV for relays connected in series

Tags: relay, surge-protection, snubber, varistor, mov

[image][image]I have 5 identical relays (same specifications) whose working input voltage is 24V DC and output voltage is 220V AC. I have a problem that voltage spike due to large capacitance when switch turns on, so I am going to build a protection circuit for relays. It has been suggested that a MOV and RC snubber circuit.

Q1. Can I use one MOV (maybe 10D471K) and one RC snubber for protecting relays connected in series?

Q2. How can I choose appropriate RC snubber?

Q3. How can I implement the protection circuit on PCB?

*upper figure is my design, lower figure is ref.

Comment: Post your circuit.